# angualr.js textAngular html view preserve returns

Tags: angularjs

I'm using textAngular as my WYSIWG editor. In the html view, is there a way to wrap this info in a `<pre></pre>` tag, or another solution to avoid the long string of html running together?

[image]

[image]

This can become very hard to manage when it is a large amount of text on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

upgrade to latest release - we added in auto formatting of the html view.